# Selenium 2 - Can't finds elements on IE

Tags: selenium

I wrote a test program with selenium 2, which works great on firefox.

But when I try it with IE9, it doesn't find the elements.

for example:

```
WebElement sh = driver.findElement(By.id("sh"));
sh.click();
```

works O.K in Firefox, but not in IE9.

I read the [next discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574802/selenium-2-0b3-ie-webdriver-click-not-firing), but it doesn't help me (I try all the suggestions) - It doesn't even find the elements, so I am not sure that this is the same problem.

Comment: are you only trying to locate your element by an id? Sometimes looking up by id fails, try using the other locator possibilities (css, xpath, class, etc.). That's the best I can tell you without your html

Comment: The IE driver for Selenium is notoriously flaky at the best of times. Are you using the latest release?

Answer (score 0):

Q: My XPath finds elements in one browser, but not in others. Why is this?
A: The short answer is that each supported browser handles XPath slightly differently, and you're probably running into one of these differences. The long answer is on the XpathInWebDriver page.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_My_XPath_finds_elements_in_one_browser,_but_not_in_others._Wh

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, the test works in FF but not in IE or Chrome. The only solution I found so far is to use the JavascriptExecutor.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", yourWebElement);
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to set same Security level in all zones. To do that follow the steps below:

Open IE

Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security

Set all zones (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter.

Finally, set Zoom level to 100% by right clicking on the gear located at the top right corner and enabling the status-bar. Default zoom level is now displayed at the lower right.