# Is there any alternative for selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webtest

I wrote tests for testing a web-site using Selenium а web driver. When I use Firefox a web driver there are no problems, but I must use IE а web driver and there are problems with it.

I read many advices for using IE web driver, when `.click()` doesn't work, but I couldn't find a panacea for resolving this problem. I tried to use **JS** insted `.click()` but this didn't resolve my problem, because I got many other problems. So may be anybody know alternative for Selenium, where I can use IE for testing?

Comment: I resolved this problem  [next way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574802/selenium-2-0b3-ie-webdriver-click-not-firing/12567403#12567403)

Comment: How have you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Sahi (http://sahi.co.in/) should be the best alternative for selenium. One can use java or javascript for the sahi scripts, php and ruby driver is also available (no personal experience with Ruby or php). Very effective with cross browser as well as cross-platform.

Some of the lovable features are: 
No explicit wait required.
For element identification _near, _under, _in etc ApI's are very useful.
Logging/Report, feature is inbuilt with Sahi.

Comment: How can I use Java with Sahi? When I recorded the tests with Sahi, the file is saved as .sah extension (for example, googlesearch.sah). How can I export/convert the .sah file into .java file?

Comment: Please go-through the url for details: 
"http://sahi.co.in/w/java"
Basically You only need to change controller.mode to java in sahi/config/sahi.properties file.
Now Sahi will record all actions and assertions in java. Which you may copy and paste to eclipse or any other java ide.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik have their own:

http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx

Watin is also another one, however it is generally abandonware.

However I will warn you that all of them have their problems with IE. This is not a fault of the dev's of the testing framework, but more a fault in IE.

The Selenium guy's cover why the IEDriver is much more flaky here:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: And there is a video of a talk given at Selenium Conference 2012 that also explains some of the challenges faced by any automation framework for IE, and how WebDriver approaches those challenges. It's available at [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myffo8o67OA&feature=plcp).

Answer (score 0):

At work we use [sikuli](http://sikuli.org/), easy to use