# Selenium To disable Position fixed Content To remove Duplicate data while taking Whole Webpage Screen shot

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, selenium-webdriver

*I am able to take screen shots of entire page by scrolling to window.innerheight but while combining facing proble of duplicate(position fixed Header/content) in all the pages.*
*Is their any solution to resolve this problem. please post your answer clearly.*[image]

**FireFox** open [Developer Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI) and hit shift + f2 then type this command.
`screenshot d:\yash.png --fullpage`
Then it reduces the clientWidth and takes screenshot.
Selenium-WebDriver FireFox-[ScreenShot](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#taking-a-screenshot)

Using **selenium with [IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917014/using-selenium-webdriver-for-internet-explorer-tests-wont-run/31336389#31336389)**(uncheck checkboxes of security & privacy and reduce Internet, Accept all cookies to zero).
use `ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);`
then it takes screenshot of entire page by reducing the client width with out any Image pixel problem. but the Screen shot on this Site:`http://help.dottoro.com/ljlumkqh.php` is not as expected.

But in **Chrome** it takes only [visible part](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294) of web page. In order to take 
whole page screen shot we need to scroll to clientHeight and combine all
screen shots.

Comment: Its selenium behaviour to take the full-page screenshot. We need not scroll explicitly to take a screenshot.

Comment: In such case, the fixed position components will not be duplicated. (selenium will pick it only once by default)

To add more info, please show us the image/screenshot captured.

Comment: Not for Firefox driver. Fixed position poblem is for chrome,IE ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove Sticky Data**

Window.[getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method and its [supported Browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle)

[currentStyle object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(v=vs.85).aspx#Standards%20information) for IE before version 9

```
var elems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
        if (window.getComputedStyle) {
             var elemStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null); 
             if(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('position') == 'fixed' && elems[i].innerHTML.length != 0 ){  
                 elems[i].parentNode.removeChild(elems[i]);
             }
        alert (Works For all Browsers);
        }else {
             var elemStyle = elems[i].currentStyle; 
             if(elemStyle.position == 'fixed' && elems[i].childNodes.length != 0 ){ 
                 elems[i].parentNode.removeChild(elems[i]); 
             }
        alert (Works for IE browsers version below 9);
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First point is you don't need to scroll for taking full screen screen shot in selenium.

**Approach for removing duplicate data:**

- Take complete window screen shot & don't save it to any file.
- Observe the duplicate data (Header object)
- Create bufferedImage object for the screen shot file using `ImageIO.read()` method.
- Get the x & y co-ordinates for the duplicate part (Header) using `.getLocation().getX()/getY()` methods.
- from whole screen shot remove the duplicate data by using `.getSubimage()` method.
- then save the image to any file using `ImageIO.write()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be some code to support your question.

But, assuming that you are scrolling your page explicitly to take the screenshot.

Solution/Suggestion/Tip: Selenium by default scrolls the page to take the screenshot of the complete page.

[image: Please refer the screenshot captured by the code.]

Code to take the above screenshot:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp");
    File myScreenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(myScreenShot, new File("D:\\ff.png"));
```

Refer [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#taking-a-screenshot) for more information on taking a screenshot.

Comment: i need for chrome Browser, whole web-page screen shot, through selenium program.