# Is their any way to disable sticky headers/footers/content for testing purpose

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

**Is their any way to disable sticky headers/footers/content for testing purpose**

*i want to take entire web page screen shot like browser extensions. like fireshot
if you know please suggest me.*

```
jse.executeScript("var el = document.getElementsByTagName('*');"
                                    + "for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){"
                                    + "   if (el[i].getAttribute(\"type\") == \"text/css\")"
                                    + "         el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);"
                                    + "};"
                                    );
```

*Iam able to [disable all css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046738/how-to-disable-css-in-browser-for-testing-purposes/18981635#18981635). but my problem is not to disable entire css only fixed/sticky header [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263885/selenium-to-disable-position-fixed-content-to-remove-duplicate-data-while-taking/31304937#31304937)*

```
ArrayList<RemoteWebElement> totalElements = (ArrayList<RemoteWebElement>) jse.executeScript("var x = document.querySelectorAll('*');"
            + "for (var i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {"
            + "if (x[i].style.position == 'fixed' || x[i].style.position == 'absolute' || x[i].style.position == 'relative') {"
            + "x[i].style.position = 'static'"
            + "}"
            + "}"
            + "return x");
```

*i am using this but not working as expected.*

Comment: I think better you tell to developer to disable temporary until you complete testing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you override only the header's css attribute? Like:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) yourDriver).executeScript("document.getElementById('the_id_of_the_header').style.position = 'static';");
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this javascript code:

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) 
{ 
  var elemStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i]);
  if(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('position') == 'fixed') 
  { 
    elems[i].style.position = 'static'; 
  } 
}
```

If you want to check more value just extend the `if` statement.

Comment: we did't know that site is using inline/internal/external css and the id-of header is unknown. We need to find all sticky headers/contents of any site for testing. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Yash: I updated my comment, please check it. I tried that with different values and it worked for me.

Comment: @Yash: the problem is with this site that a new CSS class get added after scrolling. So you should execute the JS code after scrolling down and it will work.