# Django Selenium test is failing as it can't find element which is attached after click

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, django-testing

I am trying to write a test for my application but it is currently failing. I'm not sure what the problem is but I have tried it with an `WebDriverWait` and even a `time.sleep()` but this has not solved the problem.

The failing part of the test looks like this:

```
form_2.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn-primary').click() # submits form_2 and changes page to next form
self.assertEqual(
    self.get_current_url(),
    self.live_server_url + reverse(
        'activitygroupconfigstepkeycharacteristicfieldset_update', kwargs={'activitygroupconfig_pk': 1}
    )
) # test to see if expected url is correct

# Fill out next form (i.e. Key Characteristics)
form_3 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@role="form"]')
form_3.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '#div_id_activitygroupconfigstepkeycharacteristicfield_set-0-key_characteristic'
).click()
assert form_3.find_element_by_css_selector('.select2-container--open').is_displayed() is True # I'm getting this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".select2-container--open"} here so the click clearly isn't working.
```

What should happen is that the element is clicked and then a new element is inserted into the `DOM`. But as the assertion is failing this clearly isn't happening. I have also done a `print(self.driver.page_source)` after the click and I can see that the element isn't being added so for some reason the click isn't being registered.

I thought that it may be due some custom jQuery scripts not being finished before the test takes place on the page but I added this:

```
def wait_script(self):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

after the page change and it returns `True` before the test begins, so I assume that means that all `jQuery` processes are complete, unless this doesn't take into account page specific custom functions?

Any help with this conundrum would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `.select2-container--open` element is in `//form[@role="form"]`? Would be nice if you provide relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found that the focus element for the click was wrong. See: [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574802/selenium-2-0b3-ie-webdriver-click-not-firing) which I adapted to work in my case:

```
form_3.find_element_by_id(
    'id_activitygroupconfigstepkeycharacteristicfield_set-0-key_characteristic'
).find_element_by_xpath('..').click()
```